# 'ALGOLIA_API_KEY' not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: jekyll, algolia

I am trying to run algolia for the first time but it seems that there is something wrong with my environment. I followed the detailed explanation here https://community.algolia.com/jekyll-algolia/getting-started.html.
I installed and configured everything that is needed from the previous steps but when I run the command

> ALGOLIA_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx bundle exec jekyll algolia

I get an error:

> 'ALGOLIA_API_KEY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have been rereading the documentation for both jekyll and angolia but couldn't find anything that could be helpful.

Comment: Ok so I made it work by adding a _algolia_api_key with the key to my root folder and running the command without the key value in the command.

Comment: If you've found your answer by yourself, feel free to add it as an answer and accept it yourself.
About your specific question, could you specify where you try to run this command, and which system you're on?

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using 64bit win10, I ran the command in cmd with ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running on Windows, you cannot set an environment variable for your command like you can do on UNIX.

As advised in this question, [Setting and using variable within same command line in Windows cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-and-using-variable-within-same-command-line-in-windows-cmd-exe), I believe you could use

```
set ALGOLIA_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx && bundle exec jekyll algolia
```